# Android studio not showing Toolbar option after updating 4.2

Tags: android, android-support-library

In Android studio version 4.2 has removed all v7 support library. How to create an action bar using the androidx toolbar?. I have tried, but it's not showing the title or app name on it.
Thanks

Comment: Just use the androidx libraries with the same logic.

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example for your question. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example if you are not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Toolbar XML**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

**Java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

...

Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

// set Title
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("App name");
```

Hope you helpful.

Comment: The background attribute helped me